# File reading and caching

Tags: caching, memory, file-io, filesystems

When a file is read in Java (or any language), is the data copied from disk to memory outside of the application-level buffer?  For example, how many copies of the data are made when I do the following:

```
FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
fileReader.read(buffer);
```

Other than the copy of the data written from disk to the buffer, is the data also cached by the operating system or file system?

Comment: If the OS caches the data (or makes a copy for some other reason) depends only on the OS and is not related to java

Comment: Right.  I'm curious what the most common thing for an OS like linux would do in such a situation.  I'm trying to minimize the copy overhead to maximize the speed of reading a large file.  I removed the "java" tag for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Maybe

#### Long Answer

It depends on the operating system and the filesystem chosen how many copies of any particular data are created when reading from a disk or disk-like device. All modern desktop filesystems have a read/write buffer that caches data between the application level and the physical device level. Mobile devices and embedded devices usually don't have this layer because they are writing to a memory based device and not a physical spinning disk.

*I think as SSD devices get bigger and cheaper that this level of caching on desktop devices will get much smaller, or go away completely as the SSD devices don't have the same speed issues as spinning disks do. They are still slower than main memory, but they should not require the aggressive caching that is done because of the slow access speed of spinning media.*

Comment: Excellent response.  Exactly what I was looking for.  It was hard to pin this one down through my own searches, precisely because it *depends*.